# What will happen if i remove seeds from a chilli pepper before cooking?

Tags: chili-peppers, capsaicin

Will it remove or reduce the capsaicin content?

Is there a part of the chilli I can remove to reduce or remove the capsaicin content?

Btw I know that you can use less chilli, use milder ones or bell peppers, however I'm wondering what part of the pepper the capsaicin lies in and if we can move it from a hotter pepper.

Comment: You can use less chillies and substitute some for milder peppers, say, Pepperoni, Ramiro, or even bell peppers.

Comment: no the part that has more capsain its found in the white tissue called "placenta" thats the chilis heat source... so removing the seeds wont really help at all to reduce heat.

Comment: You can watch some cooking videos on youtube or the tele. You can learn some stuff.

Comment: I don't mean to be unkind by saying this, far from it, and I understand your desire to understand. I reckon you'd learn a lot more about cooking by doing more cooking and less thinking about it. Most cooking is closer to art than to science, and getting a feel for it is more important than trying to perfect a set of ratios. Starting from recipes, tweaking them once you know what to expect (and possibly to reduce heat if you want to err on the mild side) is a good way to start.

Comment: @ChrisH well I have been cooking - a lot of it, like science experiments. However it makes sense to spend your time and efforts cooking with an educated approach.  Can you imagine if I wasted a pot of curry removing seeds to test heat reduction?  Now that I know the answer, I won't have to!

Comment: @James I see what you're getting at, but I didn't suggest wasting anything. You may think "I'm not making that again" but it's actually quite hard to make something inedible (too spicy is harder to deal with than too mild, but still fixable).

Comment: @Chris H This isn't true, both cooking and baking are all about ratios. I used to think the same as you but after using a scale for cooking, my recipes are better than ever. Too many people assume perfection, but precision (via measurements) is the only way to guarantee it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You remove the seeds for texture. You remove the white pith to reduce the capsaicin content. That way you can get the benefit of the flavour of various peppers while managing the heat.

From the ["Wiki page" on Capsacin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicin):

> Capsaicin is present in large quantities in the placental tissue (which holds the seeds), the internal membranes and, to a lesser extent, the other fleshy parts of the fruits of plants in the genus Capsicum. The seeds themselves do not produce any capsaicin, although the highest concentration of capsaicin can be found in the white pith of the inner wall, where the seeds are attached.[5]

Comment: Good Find. I knew that answer but had no proof to support it.

Comment: Gloves, or at least quickly washing hands with soap afterwards will decrease the "burning sensation under the fingernails" problem.